# Cannot open remote file

Tags: spacemacs, evil, tramp

I am trying to open a remote file in spacemacs in evil mode on windows using `SPC f f`. This pops up helm and entering `/ssh:myuser@myhost/folder/file.txt` produces

`Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

In the message area. How do I fix this?

(Note: When used with PuTTY the correct command is `/plink:myuser@myhost:/folder/file.txt`.)

Comment: This error you're getting indicates a bug somewhere.  Please report it (and/or follow the usual debugging guidelines to get a backtrace and investigate).  At the very least, the code should catch this error and replace it with another one that explains to the user what is the actual source of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a colon. The syntax is `/ssh:myuser@myhost:/folder/...`

Comment: You might be right. At least it causes a different error.

Comment: What's the error? You might want to update the question with the results.

Comment: No, I think this is good. I also had to switch to plink because I have putty installed and it has plink instead of an ssh binary but now it works.